# EventHandle in ReactJS for a particular element in a list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, list

I have component, where I make an API call and I get a response as an array of objects. Then I'm mapping through it and printing the data as rows and columns as follow:

```
{
  this.state.listUser.map((list, index) => {
    return (
      <tbody key={index}>
        <tr>
          <th>{list.first_name}</th>
          <th>{list.last_name}</th>
          <th>
            <img id={index} src={list.avatar} onClick={this.showEmailAddress} />
          </th>
          {this.state.showEmail && <th>{list.email}</th>}
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    );
  });
}
```

And onClicking the Img tag, I wanted to show the email address of that particular user. I'm not able to find how to do it for that particular item in the list. Now it show the email for all the items of the list. I want to write a `showEmailAddress` handler which will show the email for that particular item instead of all. Thanks in advance.

Here's my component:

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      listUser: "",
      showEmail: "",
    };
  }

  showEmailAddress(email) {
    this.setState({ showEmail: email });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get("https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2")
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data.data);
        this.setState({ listUser: res.data.data });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }

  render() {
    if (!this.state.listUser) {
      return <div>...loading</div>;
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>first_name</th>
            <th>last_name</th>
            <th>avatar</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        {this.state.listUser.map((list, index) => {
          return (
            <tbody key={index}>
              <tr>
                <th>{list.first_name}</th>
                <th>{list.last_name}</th>
                <th>
                  <img
                    alt="test"
                    id={index}
                    src={list.avatar}
                    onClick={this.showEmailAddress.bind(this, list.email)}
                  />
                </th>
                <th>{this.state.showEmail}</th>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: can you provide `this.showEmailAddress()` method body? that would help addressing your issue.

Comment: I have added my whole component now. Please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:
Here's a working link: https://codesandbox.io/s/unisis-test-8fejo?file=/src/App.js:0-1605

The issue was you were showing the `email` against each of the items. It should have been shown conditionally though against only that item which was clicked.

So, created an array `showList: []` which would contain the items that need to be shown and put a condition
`{this.state.showList.includes(list.id) && list.email}` where it needs to be shown.

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      listUser: "",
      showEmail: "",
      showList: []
    };
  }

  showEmailAddress(item) {
    debugger;
    this.setState({ showEmail: item.email });
    var list = this.state.showList;
    list.push(item.id);
    this.setState({showList: list})
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get("https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2")
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res.data.data);
        this.setState({ listUser: res.data.data });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }

  render() {
    if (!this.state.listUser) {
      return <div>...loading</div>;
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>first_name</th>
            <th>last_name</th>
            <th>avatar</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        {this.state.listUser.map((list, index) => {
          return (
            <tbody key={index}>
              <tr>
                <th>{list.first_name}</th>
                <th>{list.last_name}</th>
                <th>
                  <img
                    alt="test"
                    id={index}
                    src={list.avatar}
                    onClick={this.showEmailAddress.bind(this, list)}
                  />
                  <span>{this.state.showList.includes(list.id) && list.email}</span>
                </th>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: it still show email for all the items when I onClick on the img tag. CodeSandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/unisis-test-440em?file=/src/App.js

Comment: What does your `list.email` look like? Can you post the complete code especially `showEmailAddress `? Better post the complete component code

Comment: The problem is you're displaying email in every `th` you just have to add a condition so the email against the image is rendered only which is clicked

Comment: See this : https://codesandbox.io/s/unisis-test-8fejo?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215079/discussion-between-ashok-r-raghu-and-rahul-dwivedi).

Answer (score 0):

You need to just manage state in onclick of image then you can able to toggle your `<th>`

Please have a look I hope it works for you.

Thanks

```
{this.state.listUser.map((list, index) => {
      return (
        <tbody key={index}>
          <tr>
            <th>{list.first_name}</th>
            <th>{list.last_name}</th>
            <th><img id={index} src={list.avatar} onClick={this.setState({showEmail:!this.state.showEmail})}/></th>
            {this.state.showEmail &&
            <th>{list.email}</th>
            }
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      );
    })}
```